# How would i go about looping trough this tuple of files and write/read content?

Tags: python

So i have this code which checks for certain file extensions. When i run it it works fine and i get a list with all the files containing the extensions that are in the tuple. Now i want to loop trough this tuple and write something in all these files. I have tried everything i can think of but for some reason i keep getting strange errors like this (when reading): `<open file 'core.py', mode 'r' at 0x10b5195d0>.` Sorry for the bad structure in my code and the many loops, i am a beginner.

```
import os

extensions = ['docs', 'txt', 'rtf', 'py', 'doc', 'docx'] 
tree = '.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tree):
   for file in files:
       if file.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
          print(os.path.join(file))
```

Comment: Hello! Could you provide the code where you try to write to the files, please? So we can see what is wrong with that part and help you fix it.

Comment: What you are showing is not an error. It is a string representation of a file object which you are apparently printing instead of writing **to** it. But please show the actual code you are working with.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. nothing in your code attempts to read a file. no writing to either. Maybe this helps : [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I made it only operate on .txt files in a directory I didn't care about. It will crudely append something to each .txt file and then print all the lines in each file.

```
extensions = ['docs', 'txt', 'rtf', 'py', 'doc', 'docx'] 
extensions = ['txt'] 
tree = '.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tree):
   for file in files:
       if file.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
          # print(os.path.join(file))
          print(root + os.path.sep + file)
          filename = root + os.path.sep + file
          with open(filename,'at') as fw:
             fw.write('appended line\n')
          with open(filename,'r') as fr:
             lines = fr.readlines()
             for line in lines:
                 print line
```

Comment: thankyou! This cleared things up a lot. I was struggling with getting python to write / append the content to each file.